# Autocomplete in Neovim for Scala

Tags: neovim, scala-metals

I am using Neovim v0.7.2 and I am looking for a way to have autocomplete for my Neovim. Since it's suggested that we should use [Metals](https://github.com/scalameta/nvim-metals) for Scala in Neovim. After installing it, I could use its features but it seems does not support autocomplete as Intellij IDEA does. Any suggestions/recommendations for me or do I miss any part when configuring Metals with Neovim? Thank you!

SOLVED: I found the problem and post the answer below. In short, follow the example in https://github.com/scalameta/nvim-metals/discussions/39

Answer (score 1):

I miss the installation of [nvim-cmp](https://github.com/hrsh7th/nvim-cmp). The example in https://github.com/scalameta/nvim-metals/discussions/39 works perfectly.